# Bluetooth not working properly - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: bluetooth

I am using a Bluetooth USB dongle that works when I am booted into Windows 7 but does not appear to work at all in Ubuntu.

When I turn on Ubuntu and check the box to show in status bar nothing happens. When I exit Bluetooth settings then go back in, it seems that it resets the switch so Bluetooth is back off.

No idea what is causing this so please let me know if I need to provide any other information.

**EDIT:**

Also, now it says no Bluetooth adapters found. This happens sometimes when I unplug then re-plug in the dongle trying to get it to work.

**EDIT 2:**
`lsusb` while the device is plugged in

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 045e:0779 Microsoft Corp. LifeCam HD-3000
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 04b4:0101 Cypress Semiconductor Corp. Keyboard/Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 011 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 010 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 003: ID 0930:6544 Toshiba Corp. TransMemory-Mini / Kingston DataTraveler 2.0 Stick (2GB)
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 1bcf:0005 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
`
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: Done. I can't see anything there, because right now it is disconnected, but sometimes it doesn't say "No bluetooth adapters found" in the bluetooth settings.

Comment: So plug in the dongle and give the output of `lsusb`. To format the output please use the `{}` button. The output without the dongle is useless.

Comment: Done. I didn't mean it isn't plugged in, I meant that it doesn't seem to be connected despite being plugged into a USB port.

Comment: `lspci` was a typo. I need `lsusb`. And please do not add it with EDIT1, EDIT2, etc. Remove all the outputs and post a relevant one.

Comment: And what is plugged in? What is `Toshiba Corp. TransMemory-Mini `?

Comment: Okay, lsusb is on there, as I said the bluetooth dongle is plugged in.

Toshiba Corp. ..... is a USB drive, a webcam, keyboard and mouse are plugged in too.

Comment: What else is plugged in?

Comment: Toshiba Corp. ..... is a USB drive, a webcam, keyboard and mouse are plugged in too.

Comment: So, there is no BT device listed. Then it won't work. It is not related to the OS. If it is seen and is not working, it can be fixed probably.

Comment: Okay, I will try to get it connected. The same thing works in Windows 7 just fine.